# fullpage.js + reportcard.js .js error

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js theme and reportcard.js widget on my personal github pages website and I'm getting a spinning loading graphic... it was showing me some error in the .js and i commented out the code (line 45 of reportcard.js)

Also, I've been having some issues formatting the elements... it seems that example3.css (fullpage) is conflicting with reportcards css.. I'm not really sure how all the code formatting works on Stack Overflow so here are my links:

GitHub repo:
https://github.com/twotimes22/twotimes22.github.io

Domain:
http://www.thomasweld.com/

FullPage.js:
alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

ReportCard.js:
reportcard.rileyh.com/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And why are you even using `example3.css`? That's the code for the fullPage.js example website. You can use your own css styles.

Comment: I'm new to coding.. html, css, javascript..everything. I figured the more files and settings I could leave the same when getting my site up and running the better, I've been customizing with my own css now that everything else is functioning properly. - Thanks for the reply